# How can i extract the order id from below stringy json in jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, extractor

How to extract the order id from below code

```
{"status": "OK", "data": {"ExecutionComplete": true, "Result": "{\"status\": \"OK\", \"data\": {\"orderId\": \"order_JUDoycmj5SoERg\"}, \"statusCode\": 200}", "JobState": "SUCCESS"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for 2 [JSON JMESPath Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor):

1. First to get `Result` attribute value from the response

   [image]
2. Second to get `orderId` attribute value from `${Result}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   [image]

   [image]
3. Once done you will be able to refer the extracted value as `${orderId}` where required

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)